# Calling mint function from UI causes Error minting character Error: cannot estimate gas

Tags: solidity

im testing a contract but cant seem to get it to work from the ui. the hardhat task works after adding the `value` property, but not sure how to implement it when minting from the ui.

hardhat task:

```
task("mint", "Mints from the NFT contract")
    .addParam("address", "The address to receive a token")
    .setAction(async function (taskArguments, hre) {
        const contract = await getContract("NFT", hre);
        const transactionResponse = await contract.mintTo(taskArguments.address, {
            gasLimit: 500_000,
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.004")
        });
        console.log(`Transaction Hash: ${transactionResponse.hash}`);
    });
```

contract mint function:

```
  function mintTo(address recipient) public payable returns (uint256) {
    uint256 tokenId = currentTokenId.current();
    require(tokenId < TOTAL_SUPPLY, "Max supply reached");
    require(msg.value == MINT_PRICE, "Transaction value did not equal the mint price");

    currentTokenId.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = currentTokenId.current();
    _safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
    return newItemId;
  }
```

part of ui function where im sending the `currentAccount` but dont know how to send the value like in the hardhat task.

```
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(
      nftContractAddress,
      NFT.abi,
      signer
    )

    let nftTx = await nftContract.mintTo(currentAccount)
    console.log('Minting....', nftTx.hash)
```

I tried adding the value as a second param, but it returns this: `Error minting character Error: non-payable method cannot override value`

```
let nftTx = await nftContract.mintTo(currentAccount, {
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.004")
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I was referring to the wrong contract. Code above is good to go for calls to a smart contract method.